# Pandas - Extract unmatched word of sentence in a column by comparing other columns value (word) in the same data frame

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Input:

I have a Dataframe as follows

```
Full_Name                     Name1          Name2 
John Mathew Davidson          John           Davidson
Paul Theodre Luther           Paul           Theodre
Victor George Mary            George         Mary
```

Output:

I need to find the Remaining_name column as shown below

```
Full_Name                     Name1       Name2       Remaining_name
John Mathew Davidson          John        Davidson       Mathew
Paul Theodre Luther           Paul        Theodre        Luther
Victor George Mary            George      Mary           Victor
```

Clarification:

I need to compare more than one column's value (word) in another column's value (sentence)  and find the unmatched words which could be in any position of the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

Vectorized solution using replace,

```
df['Remaining_name'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Full_Name'].replace(x['Name1'], '').replace(x['Name2'], ''), axis=1).str.strip()


    Full_Name               Name1   Name2       Remaining_name
0   John Mathew Davidson    John    Davidson    Mathew
1   Paul Theodre Luther     Paul    Theodre     Luther
2   Victor George Mary      George  Mary        Victor
```

Edit: If you have many columns starting with Name, you can select a slice a replace the values in Full_Name based on regex pattern

```
df['tmp'] = df[df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Name')]].apply('|'.join, axis = 1)
df['Remaining_name'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.replace(x['tmp'], '', regex = True), axis = 1)['Full_Name'].str.strip()
df.drop('tmp', axis =1, inplace = True)


    Full_Name                   Name1   Name2       Remaining_name
0   John Mathew Davidson        John    Davidson    Mathew
1   Paul Theodre Luther         Paul    Theodre     Luther
2   Victor George Mary          George  Mary        Victor
3   Henry Patrick John Harrison Henry   John        Patrick Harrison
```

Comment: Thanks Vaishali. It helped to solve the problem 

In this scenario, is there a way to combine "replace" and "filter" to find the column names like "Name"? 

I mean, if there are 5 columns that starts with Name[1,2,3...5 ] and i would want something as follows ? 

df.apply(lambda x:  x['Full_Name'].replace(x.filter(like='Name'),''),axis=1).str.strip()

Thanks for hearing..!

Answer (score 1):

This is the data you provided:

```
import pandas as pd

full_name = ['John Mathew Davidson', 'Paul Theodre Luther', 'Victor George Mary']
name_1 = ['John', 'Paul', 'George']
name_2 = ['Davidson', 'Theodre', 'Mary']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Full_Name':full_name, 'Name1':name_1, 'Name2':name_2 })
```

In order to perform an action on multiple columns in a row, best thing is to define the function separately. It makes the code more readable and easier to debug
The function will take a DataFrame row as an input:

```
def find_missing_name(row):

    known_names = [row['Name1'], row['Name2']] ## we add known names to a list to check it later    

    full_name_list = row['Full_Name'].split(' ') ## converting the full name to the list by splitting it on spaces

    ## WARNING! this function works well only if you are sure your 'Full_Name' column items are separated by a space.

    missing_name = [x for x in full_name_list if x not in known_names] ## looping throught the full name list and comparing it to the known_names list, to only keep the missing ones.
    missing_name = ','.join(missing_name) ## in case there are more than one missing names convert them all in a string separated by comma

    return missing_name
```

Now apply the function to the existing DataFrame:

```
df['missing_name'] = df.apply(find_missing_name, axis=1) ## axis=1 means 'apply to each row', where axis=0 means 'apply to each column'
```

Output:
[image]

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do so in one line with:

```
df['Remaining_name'] = df.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x['Full_Name'].split() if all(i not in x[c] for c in df.columns[1:])], axis=1)
```

This will return your `Remaining_name` column as a `list`, but this functionality will be helpful in the case that you have names with more than three sub-strings, for example:

```
                     Full_Name    Name1     Name2    Remaining_name
0         John Mathew Davidson     John  Davidson          [Mathew]
1          Paul Theodre Luther     Paul   Theodre          [Luther]
2           Victor George Mary   George      Mary          [Victor]
3  Henry Patrick John Harrison  Patrick     Henry  [John, Harrison]
```

Comment: Thanks @rahlf23 . Is there a way i can get these values not as a list but just as a comma separated value ? 

Thanks a lot for the foreseen scenario

Comment: Sure just use `','.join(_____)`